# Azure data studio R code execution fails when Random seed set with single quote used as in RNGKind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")

Tags: r, azure, escaping, azure-sql-database, string-formatting

Code cell execution fails when trying to execute R code with SQL kernel in Azure data studio

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
       @language = N'R'
     , @script = N'
       RNGKind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
       set.seed(123)
'
```

Problem is the single quote given in `RNGKind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")` closes the single quote opened after  `@script = N'` and throws error. Any thoughts on how to approach it, or perhaps if there is a way to execute script using file name?

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-r-create-script?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: two single quotes after L:  `("L''Ecuyer-CMRG")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to repro the issue as, we could avoid such issues using multiple `'` in the syntax.

[image]

It works fine without an error.